# Countdown timer for reveal.js / html slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, reveal.js

I want to integrate a countdown timer on specific slides in my reveal.js deck.

To achieve this, I used code from [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/yLywVbW) and integrated this into my slideshow. It works nicely for the first instance of the timer, but does not appear when I try to add the timer to a second slide.

```js
// the js code for the timer (source: https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/yLywVbW)
// Credit: Mateusz Rybczonec

const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};

const TIME_LIMIT = 20;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;

startTimer();

function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const {
    alert,
    warning,
    info
  } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}

// this code is to initialize the slideshow
Reveal.initialize({
  hash: true,
});
```

```css
/* all css is for the timer*/

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
}

.base-timer {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.base-timer__svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.base-timer__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 1s linear all;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
  color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
  color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.6.0/js/reveal.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.6.0/css/reveal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <title>reveal.js</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/highlight/monokai.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="reveal">
    <div class="slides">
      <section>the timer appears here<br>
        <div id="app"></div>
      </section>
      <section>but does not appear here<br>
        <div id="app"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I'm not very versed with Javascript.. can anybody tell me what I can do to get the second instance of the timer working?

Comment: After getting no reaction here, I asked this question [on github](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/3140)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [reveal-countdown plugin](https://github.com/christer79/reveal_countdown) already provides this feature, no need to build it on your own! You can install it by downloading the repo and adding it to plugins/countdown or via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reveal.js-countdown)